# Figure not getting referenced after one Figure*

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption

I have used `figure*` environment to include multiple subfigures in a single figure in a double-column article in Overleaf. I have also included `graphicx` and `subcaption` package.

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{train_success.png}
  \caption{An image from training set}
  \label{fig:train_succ}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{validation_success.png}
  \caption{An image from validation set}
  \label{fig:valid_succ}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Output of Mask RCNN on various images}
\label{fig:mask_rcnn_train_results}
\end{figure*}

bla bla bla \ref{fig:mask_rcnn_train_results} % working fine

some random text \ref{fig:8_point} % prints ??

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{8 point.png}
    \caption{8 points considered in 8-point method}
    \label{fig:8_point}
\end{figure}
```

The figure of the `figure*` environment actually gets printed at the top of the next page and it is getting referenced perfectly using `\ref`.

But any other figure after the figure* environment (here the figure {fig:8_point}) is not getting referenced from any point of the tex file using `\ref`. I get ?? in the place of `\ref` (for the above case, I get "some random text ??"). Also, the image `8 point.png` is being completely ignored. However, any figure added before the `figure*` environment is getting referenced properly using `\ref`.

Does `figure*` environment break anything? If so, how to add multiple subfigures in a single figure in a double-column article without using `figure*`? I am using XeLaTeX compiler and `\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}` as documentclass (ACM format, author's draft).

Here is a working example (I'm using Overleaf):

```
\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural
  Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
  June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}
    
\begin{document}

\title{A Random Title}

\author{Preetom Saha Arko}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\section{Literature Review}

\section{Problem Definition}
A sample image from the dataset has been shown in Figure \ref{fig:sample}. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A sample image from dataset}
    \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\section{Implementation}
\subsection{Training Model}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{An image from training set}
  \label{fig:train_succ}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{An image from validation set}
  \label{fig:valid_succ}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{An image unseen by model}
  \label{fig:outside_succ1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{An image unseen by model}
  \label{fig:outside_succ2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Output of model on various images}
\label{fig:mask_rcnn_train_results}
\end{figure*}

In Figure \ref{fig:mask_rcnn_train_results}, the output of model on some images has been shown. Figure \ref{fig:train_succ} shows an image from the training set and Figure \ref{fig:valid_succ} shows an image from the validation set. Figure \ref{fig:outside_succ1} and Figure \ref{fig:outside_succ2} show two images that are neither from the training set nor from the validation set. Here we see that the model performs reasonably well on all these images.

\subsection{Image Processing}
These points have been shown in a rectangle in Figure \ref{fig:8_point}. 
% prints ?? in the place of ref

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{8 points considered}
    \label{fig:8_point}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}

\end{document}
```

You can also find the working example [here](http://overleaf.com/read/hkyqzswvxdvr).

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that alows others to reproduce the output you get. What exactly does "is not getting referenced from any point of the tex file"  refer to?

Comment: you mean `\ref` does not work? that usually is due to a mis-placed `\label` ie an error in the figure that you have not shown.

Comment: @leandriis I have edited my question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added an example. Label is ok here, I guess.

Comment: @PreetomSahaArko: I have no problem here, wrapping your code snippet into a `twocolumn` document ([source](https://pastebin.com/raw/1Z6010NT)). So, this might have to do with something else you're not providing, like the `\documentclass`. Can you provide a *complete* minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`? For reference on examples, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: @Werner I am using \documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart} , which is a 2 column ACM format for author's draft.

Comment: don't ask people to try to reproduce the problem by guessing random changes. It is _much_ easier for you to make an example as you have the document with the problem, all you need to do is delete everything that you can delete while still showing the issue.

Comment: I have created a smaller dummy version of my Overleaf project here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hkyqzswvxdvr (added in the question)

Comment: Please add your example directly into the question on this site. Links to external sites can expire making this question useless for potential future visitors.

Comment: no please edit the question. your question is archived here forever and will not be understandable if you edit that overleaf project

Comment: However I did look at your overleaf project note the red **16** after _any_ error you shouldn't look at the pdf file it sis not intended to be usable. You have 16 errors reported you need to fix those first before worrying about references in the output/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the Overleaf project. Now there is no error. Still the referencing shows ??

Comment: If I run your code it produces Figure 3  (needs two runs as usual) [see this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxETS.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Can you post a `.log` file somewhere? I have the same problem as the OP, with an up-to-date TeX Live distribution. The `figure` *after* `figure*` is just ignored within the output.

Comment: My [`\listfiles`](https://pastebin.com/raw/9AJcE9ka), running `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.9)`.

Comment: IEEE Transaction format prints everything correctly. Maybe figure* environment has  some issues with the documentclass of ACM.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, too, using MikTeX (up-to-date) and xelatex (but have no clue about the cause, my LaTeX skills are not good enough for this one).